# magento product image swatch

Tags: magento, product, thumbnails

i need to somehow link a thumnail image, to a different full sized, base image.

my products are a configurable/simple combination.

how can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there's a better way to do it but you could prob hack it by overwriting the full-size image with the image you want to show. This should work since Magento opens images by the filename and will show what you overwrote the old image with.

Just remember if you do this, you might need to clear cache to see difference.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use an already made extension for that purposes. Try this one [Product Color Swatch](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-color-swatch.html)